# How to 'hide' an extra text in word2010

Tags: microsoft-word

how can I 'hide' an extra text? For example, if I have one paragraph and I have to highligh the important words, but I do not want to see the extra information, which I have to keep as well, because they are connected and if I forget for what are the keywords just to click on the hidden text, so he could show and to rememeber.

What I have:

**According to the graph, the population in** India **will increase more quickly than in** China and experts say that by 2030, both countries will have the same population of 1.45 billion. **After this,** China’s population **is likely to** fall slightly to 1.4 billion in 2050, **while** India’s population will probably increase and reach 1.6 billion.

What I want to become:

**According to the graph, the population in** (...) **will increase more quickly than in** (...). **After this,** (...) **is likely to** (...), **while** (...).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could create a text in a form of:

**According to the graph, the population in (...) will increase more quickly than in (...). After this, (...) is likely to (...), while (...).**

Then in all places like "(...)" insert a footnote with the text that you want to remember. Then change color of all footnotes and footnote references to background color (white). What will be different from your requirement is that you should hover over "(...)" instead of clicking to see the hidden text.

Edit: changing color of a footnote text/reference can be done by changing two styles, not individual footnote references, this means it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect solution, but you could make the text very very small (like 1 pt font). This way, you can't read the text, but if you change the font size back, you'll be able to read it again. And you can use Format Painter to do this quickly.